# Database collation - Change Impact

Tags: sql-server, database, collation

I am really weak as far as databases are concerned so, please bear with me. 
I have a database which is in Greek.CI_AI working without any issue with several applications. All servers that put data into this DB are on Greek locale.

However, an application treats its information and checks integrity constraints in a case-sensitive manner. I have not run into any issues with the specific application so far but I am concerned that I may have to deal with it later when the data will be more and the impact even bigger. What is the proper way to do this? I mean do I just change it or should I drop it and recreate it with the right collation? If I do not have to drop it, how will this affect the data?

Comparing the two I have not found differences.

http://collation-charts.org/mssql/mssql.0408.1253.Greek_CI_AI.html
http://collation-charts.org/mssql/mssql.0408.1253.Greek_CS_AI.html

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Also, what is the difference between Greek.CI_AI and Greek.BIN?

Answer (score 2):

You should not change your db collation from Greek_CI_AI to Greek_CS_AI/BIN.
If your application checks integrity constraints in a **case-sensitive** manner it just means that your business rules require this approach and this case sensitivity is implemented directly in those constraints.

If you change database collation to Greek_CS_AI you can just break application code. If there are tables `Table1` and `Table2` in your database now, all the code can reference them as `table1` and `table2`, but once your db collation becomes case sensitive, the objects `table1` and `table2` will not be found.

> Also, what is the difference between Greek.CI_AI and Greek.BIN

To view this by your eyes, try to do some selects of your data adding `ORDER BY col1 COLLATE Greek_CS_AI --Greek_CS_BIN` to your `SELECT` statement

You'll find that in first case your uppercase/lowercase letters will be placed next to each other but lowercase will always precede uppercase within the same letter while in the second(BIN) case ALL the uppercase letters will precede ALL the lowercase letters like this:

[image]

This is because `BIN` collation compare characters based on their ascii codes.

Note that there is a bug in `BIN` collations that compare correctly only the first character of the string, for this reason if you ever need to use binary collation always use `BIN2` collations that have no bug